# How to best set up heterogeneous work loads in celery?

Tags: python, celery, scientific-computing

I'm currently trying to set up an experiment with `celery` that consists of two phases.

In the first phase a kind of job is run that produces the inputs for the second kind of job.

The first workflow I tried looked roughly like this:

```py
result = group(jobs_in_phase1)()
result.join()
result = group(jobs_in_phase2)()
result.join()
```

Unfortunately this turned out to be insufficient: I have 2GB of RAM per core which is fine for jobs of kind 2, which are mostly CPU-bound. Jobs of kind 1 are very heterogeneous in their runtime and RAM consumption: some run very short and need little RAM, others run very long and need loads of RAM (let's assume 16GB at max). If I run the experiment now with the code above, many jobs in phase 1 will crash because of memory exhaustion.

What I'm doing right now is something like this:

```
for chunk in chunks(jobs_in_phase1, 32):
    result = group(chunk)()
    result.join()
result = group(jobs_in_phase2)()
result.join()
```

This runs at most 32 jobs at once in phase 1. This seems to suffice that every job in phase 1 has enough RAM. Unfortunately it makes no good use of my computational resources since most jobs in a chunk will finish fast with only few running for a long time (and before these are finished, no new chunk can start).

Is there a simple way to tell `celery` to run, say, 8 jobs in parallel in phase 1 and 128 jobs in parallel in phase two? Or is there even a better way that takes into account the actual RAM usage when deciding which jobs to start?